# Find a basis for the eigenspace corresponding to the eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

The given matrix and eigenvalue are $$A = \begin{bmatrix}10 & -9 \\ 4 & -2 \end{bmatrix} \space  \lambda=4$$
Applying the eigenvalue to the matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}10-4 & -9 \\ 4 & -2-4 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}6 & -9 \\ 4 & -6 \end{bmatrix}$$
Then taking the determinant
$$\begin{vmatrix}6 & -9 \\ 4 & -6 \end{vmatrix}=-36-(-36)=0$$
This is where I'm lost, does this mean the eigenspace is the zero vector or that the eigenspace doesn't exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $\det(A-\lambda I)$ will always be zero. That's almost the *definition* of eigenvalue.

To find the eigenspace, you have to find all vectors $v$ for which $(A-\lambda I)v=0$. In your case, that is all $(x,y)$ for which
$$\begin{bmatrix}6 & -9 \\ 4 & -6 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y \end{bmatrix}=0$$
Can you take it from there?

Comment: Yeah its just a system of equations, I don't know why I thought I needed to take the determinant.